# How to compress ttf font file

Tags: spring, pdf, fonts, pdf-generation, pdfbox

I need to have a font to support a few languages including German, Swedish, and simplified Chinese. I created ttf with merged different fonts that support each language. File size became more than 22 megabytes. After I use the font to generate PDF with `PDDocument` the output file also appeared to be very big size (20+ Mb).

How can I reduce file sizes?

Comment: Which library is this? iText has https://api.itextpdf.com/pdfOptimizer/java/2.0.1/com/itextpdf/pdfoptimizer/handlers/FontSubsettingOptimizer.html to take out unused glyphs, you can either process your final PDF with iText or find out if your library support similar function.

Comment: `PDDocument` seems to indicate PDFBox usage.

Comment: PDFBox does font subsetting. Unless you're dealing with AcroForm PDFs where the full font might be needed.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr yes, unfortunately I have to use  AcroForm PDFs